# Why I am not able to extract the object using the masked image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here are two images in the drive, one is masked and another one is real image:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hv3NLQeIHT5Iicgnt74S5qFRG5aJyMLw?usp=sharing

I want to get the masked object out of the real image, not in the white color but in the actual color that it does have.

Here is the code that I hav written:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('im010.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('im010.png')

img_foreground = np.array((mask/255)*img)

cv2.imshow('', img_foreground)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have converted all masked elements into one, and multiplied it with the actual image. Since the rest of the pixels that are not masked are black, there it will be zero. If any number multiply with it, it remains zero. Multiplication with one value element ends up the same value of the real image. But I have ploted it, it is showing the same masked img?

Can anyone show me the solution?

Comment: change it to ```img_foreground = np.array((mask/255)*img)/255```

Comment: #Nin17, When I am saving this image with the cropped images, it is saving the black images, why it is happening?

Comment: try removing all the ```/255``` also you use @ not # to notify someone

Comment: Bitwise-and will work as well.

Comment: Please attach the image to the post, links to external sites are not suitable because these links can break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code just needs an additional `/255`.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('im010.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('im010.png')

img_foreground = np.array((mask/255)*(img/255))

cv2.imshow('', img_foreground)
cv2.waitKey()
```

that's because, when you look at the values, they're floats, right? and when they're floats, they must be in the range of 0.0 to 1.0, because that's what `imshow` expects.

when you give it values scaled differently, it still maps 1.0 to white. any larger value (like 2, 3...) is also white, even if they would be shown as very dark in a range of 0..255, which goes for `uint8` type input.

Answer (score 3):

Here are 4 different ways to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread('im010.jpg')


# Method 1 -- Bitwise_And

mask = cv2.imread('im010.png',0)
result1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
cv2.imwrite('im010_masked1.jpg', result1)
cv2.imshow("result1", result1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Method 2 -- Python Multiplication

mask = cv2.imread('im010.png')
result2 = (img * mask.astype(np.float64)/255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('im010_masked2.jpg', result2)
cv2.imshow("result2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Method 3 -- Numpy Blackening

mask = cv2.imread('im010.png',0)
result3 = img.copy()
result3[mask==0] = (0,0,0)
cv2.imwrite('im010_masked3.jpg', result3)
cv2.imshow("result3", result3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Method 4 -- Numpy Where

mask = cv2.imread('im010.png')
result4 = np.where(mask==255, img, mask)
cv2.imwrite('im010_masked4.jpg', result4)
cv2.imshow("result4", result4)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

They all produce the following result:

[image]

Comment: 4 flavours in 1 cup :)